# Incorrect syntax near 'NULL'

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Below is the syntax for a `CREATE TABLE` query I'm using to create a temporary table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ZipCodeTerritoryTemp](
    [ChannelCode] [char](1) NOT NULL,
    [DrmTerrDesc] [nvarchar](30) NOT NULL,
    [IndDistrnId] [char](3) NULL,
    [StateCode] [char](3) NOT NULL,
    [ZipCode] [char](9) NULL,
    [EndDate] [date] NOT NULL,
    [EffectiveDate] [date] NOT NULL,
    [LastUpdateId] [char](8) NULL,
    [LastUpdateDate] [date] NULL,
    [Id] [int] NULL,
    [ErrorCodes] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Status] [char](1) NULL
```

For whatever reason I am getting the following error message in SQL Server Management Studio

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 16
>   Incorrect syntax near 'NULL'

This script looks fine to me, however I haven't done much with SQL in awhile. Can anyone either A) let me know what I'm doing wrong or B) tell me how to interpret these error messages from Management Studio?

Comment: Allow me to +1 you on this one. The folks who down voted the question might thought that it obvious, but this question is actually very helpful. Finding the question (and answers) took less time then analyzing the CREATE query to find the missing bracket (and the error message wasn't helping much).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Is that the complete code? If so there is a closing ')' missing.

Answer (score 6):

You are missing the closing `)`

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ZipCodeTerritoryTemp](
    [ChannelCode] [char](1) NOT NULL,
    [DrmTerrDesc] [nvarchar](30) NOT NULL,
    [IndDistrnId] [char](3) NULL,
    [StateCode] [char](3) NOT NULL,
    [ZipCode] [char](9) NULL,
    [EndDate] [date] NOT NULL,
    [EffectiveDate] [date] NOT NULL,
    [LastUpdateId] [char](8) NULL,
    [LastUpdateDate] [date] NULL,
    [Id] [int] NULL,
    [ErrorCodes] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Status] [char](1) NULL
)
```